# Generate Avro schema from C# class

Tags: c#, .net, avro

I am wondering if there is a tool can get information from C# class file and generate Avro schema. Just like Protobuf-net, which provide attributes and some tool that no need to ask user to implement schema file manually.

```
[ProtoContract]
class Person {
[ProtoMember(1)]
public int Id {get;set;}
[ProtoMember(2)]
public string Name {get;set;}
[ProtoMember(3)]
public Address Address {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Can you please show an example of an Avro class instead? Unclear what output you're expecting. Avro also **requires** a reader **and writer** schema.

Answer (score -2):

we use PropertyInfo to get all the custom attributes

Sorry I can not paste all the codes:)

**the attribute define**

```
﻿using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class EditAttribute : Attribute
{
    public EditType Type{ get; set; }
}
```

**the entry class**

```
public class Admin
{
    [Edit(Type = EditType.Int, IsNumber = true, IsKey = true, Show = ShowType.All)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

**the method to get the attributes**

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    EditAttribute editContent = (EditAttribute)property.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(EditAttribute));
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Avro?